# Multiple Author and email with location?

Tags: affiliation, email

I am trying to add multiple Author with their email and location but not working.

I am trying to get something like this

```
   first_person^1 , second person^2, third_person^3

          {1^mail, 2^mail, 3^mail}@gmail.com

                 institution name
                     location
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem to your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\SUP\textsuperscript
\title{Foo and bar}
\author{first\_person\SUP{1}, second\_person\SUP{2}, third\_person\SUP{3}\\[\bigskipamount]
\{\SUP{1}mail, \SUP{2}mail, \SUP{3}mail\}@gmail.com}
\date{institution name\\location}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was facing same issue, but date is not working in latex in overleaf?