# How to write multiple author name and location?

Tags: tables, titles, overleaf

I am trying to add multiple Author and institute  name with location but it's not working.

What I have tried is:

```
\begin{document}
\title{Multi label classification}
\author[1]{John S}
\author[2]{Prbhu M}
\author[3]{Three}
\affil[1]{US}
```

I am looking for like this:

[image]

How to add multiple emails like that with location and institute?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please register your account then you can edit your first same question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501114/multiple-author-and-email-with-location  and add there the needed compilable tex code, i.e. start with `\documentclass` and end the tex code with `\end{document}` ...

Comment: @Mensch Can you tell me how to write more author email?

Comment: No I can not. It depends for example on the documentclass you are using you did not tell us ... Perhaps you have already loaded packages handling such informations we can not know because we saw no compilable tex code resulting in your issue .... Just believe there is much reason why we ask for an mwe, an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ...