# Multiple Author and email with location in overleaf?

Tags: spacing, pdftex, titles, author

I am trying to add multiple Author name in my paper but not getting satisfactory result. I am using overleaf and my code looks like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Foo and bar}
\author{first\_person\SUP{1}, second\_person\SUP{2}, third\_person\SUP{3}\\[\bigskipamount]
\{\SUP{1}mail, \SUP{2}mail, \SUP{3}mail\}@gmail.com}
\date{institution name\\location}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

But it's not working, It's coming out like this:

[image]

What I am looking for is :

[image]

Also \date is not working in overleaf, How I can write author names and location like above image in overleaf?

> Update :

Full code

```
%\title{Deep Learning}
%% 2012/12/27
%% by the Captain 

% OPTIONAL PACKAGES
%\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\include{pythonlisting}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
%  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\else
%  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%\fi
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage{stfloats}
% \usepackage{dblfloatfix}
%\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
%  \usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}
% \let\MYoriglatexcaption\caption
% \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{\MYoriglatexcaption[#2]{#2}}
%\fi
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}


\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\begin{document}
\let\SUP\textsuperscript

\title{Preparation of Camera-Ready Contributions to SCITEPRESS Proceedings}
\author{first_name\SUP{1}, second_name\SUP{2}, third_name\SUP{3}

\{\SUP{1}first, \SUP{2}second, \SUP{3}third\}@gmail.com}
\date{institution name\\location}





\IEEEtitleabstractindextext{%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should summarize the contents of the paper and should contain at least 70 and at most 200 words. The text must be set to 9-point font size.
\end{abstract}}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\IEEEdisplaynontitleabstractindextext
\end{document}
```

Thank you !

Comment: When you copy code from [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501227/48973), make sure to mention it and to not leave out any lines. You omitted the definition of `\SUP`, which TeX tells you by issuing error messages. _Don't ignore error messages!_

Comment: Also, when I run your example code on Overleaf, I don't get the output you posted. Both `\\[\bigskipamount]` and `\date` work fine.

Comment: @schtandard first issue is solved but \date is still not working, can I use any other function instead of \date to display location and institution name?

Comment: As I said, the MWE from the answer you copied from works just fine in Overleaf for me. Either you are not showing us the code you are actually compiling, or there is something wrong with your Overleaf account specifically, in which case this is off-topic here and you should contact Overleaf support.

Comment: @schtandard Sorry for that, I have updated full code, please take a look

Comment: @schtandard it's because of this line `\documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}` but how do solve this then?

Comment: Well, the class `IEEEtran` does not use the date in the title. If you want, you can add it to the `\author`, just like the email addresses. If you actually want to submit your document to a paper, they might not be happy about you "misusing" their `\author` command, though.

Comment: In the future, please make sure that your code example actually is an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that is, a small complete document that _reproduces your problem_. A long document with many unnecessary lines like you posted is not very helpful and will likely lead to less people trying to help you.